# How configure fsync for specific command in redis

Tags: redis

I try to find about custom AOF configuration. I found [only that](http://redis.io/topics/persistence):

> There are three options:
>
> 1. fsync every time a new command is appended to the AOF. Very very slow, very safe.
> 2. fsync every second. Fast enough (in 2.4 likely to be as fast as snapshotting), and you can lose 1 second of data if there is a disaster.
> 3. Never fsync, just put your data in the hands of the Operating System. The faster and less safe method.

Can I configure  fsync which every time append a command to the AOF only for specific command (INCR)?
Is it possible ?

Answer (score 2):

You could do that with a MULTI/EXEC block, i.e.:

```
MULTI
CONFIG SET appendfsync always
INCR somekey
CONFIG SET appendfsync no
EXEC
```